# Freemarker: getting a Template with include (prefix)

Tags: list, templates, freemarker

Im trying the following:

**MainTemplate.ftl**

```
<root>
  <#List items as item>
    <#include "custom_item.ftl">  [Option 1]
  </#List>  
  <#include "custom_item.ftl">    [Option 2]
</root>
```

**custom_item.ftl**

```
<root>
  <name>${name}</name>
</root>
```

In some files the include is like [Option 1], in others as [Option 2].
To access the ${name} variable i have to use 2 different ways:

```
- Option 1: ${item.name}
- Option 2: ${name}
```

Totally understandable, but also my issue. How can i make sure it always works? Like supplying a prefix to the include so its always the same.

For example like:

**MainTemplate.ftl**

```
<root>
  <#List items as item>
    <#include "custom_item.ftl" prefix='item'>  [Option 1]
  </#List>  
  <#include "custom_item.ftl">    [Option 2]
</root>
```

**custom_item.ftl**

```
<root>
  <# assign prefix = prefix?root>
  <name>${prefix.name}</name>
</root>
```

Which then always would work. My approach clearly doesnt work, does someone has a solution that does work?

> **Edit: Answer included**

**MainTemplate.ftl**

```
<root>
  <#List listItems as listItem>
    <#assign item = listItem>
    <#include "custom_item.ftl">  
  </#List>  
  <#assign item = .data_model>
  <#include "custom_item.ftl">    
</root>
```

**custom_item.ftl**

```
<root>
  <name>${item.name}</name>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use `${item.name}`. In the case when the data-model root itself is the item (is it?), you can do something like `<#assign item = .data_model>` before the `#include`.